# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str' using GITPYTHON

Tags: python, git, typeerror, gitpython

I am using gitpython to do some file processing. Everything is working fine, except for the d.new_file condition where I encountered this type error where i can't concatenate NoneType and str together.

I think that d.a_path is None, but I cannot figure out why it is not working but it is working in the else condition.

```
for d in repo.head.commit.diff(None,create_patch=True):
    if d.deleted_file: 
        print( "deleted file")

    elif d.new_file:
        print(" new_file")

        with open(main_dir,'a+') as main_file:
            main_file.write(d.a_path +'\n')

    elif d.renamed_file:
        print("renamed file")   

    else:
        print(" modified file")

        with open(main_dir,'a') as main_file:
            main_file.write(d.a_path+"\n")

        handle_diff(d.diff)
```

Anybody knows why d.a_path is None for d.new_file condition ?

Answer (score 1):

This is [documented behaviour](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.diff.Diff):

> There are a few cases where None has to be expected as member variable value:
>
> New File:
>
> ```
> a_mode is None
> a_blob is None
> a_path is None
> ```
>
> Deleted File:
>
> ```
> b_mode is None
> b_blob is None
> b_path is None
> ```

The path of the new file should be in `b_path` for a new file, not in `a_path`, since the file didn't exist in `a`.